# how to make the enemy follow the player in platformer game made in godot

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

hello guys i made the enemy mechanics in godot and i want him to follow the player but i got lost in tutorials and most of it in RPG game so i hope to help me. i make a state that is "Follow" and i make when the player entered the area the enemy play attention animation and when the attention finished it call the follow function. i want to ask if any body have a solution for my problem or if have a best way to do it ??
And this enemy code to help you:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed = 50
var motion = Vector2()
var gravity = 30
var dir = 1
var state_machine
var can_move = true
var current_state = States.RUN
onready var player = get_node("/root/exp/Boxer King")


enum States {
    RUN
    Attack
    Follow
    Attention
}

# Reference to Timer node
onready var timer = $Timer
onready var RayFloor = $RayFloor
onready var RayWall = $RayWall


func _physics_process(delta):
    
    state_machine = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")
    
    # gravity 
    motion.y += gravity
    
    match current_state:
        States.RUN:
            handle_movement()
        States.Attack:
            state_machine.travel("attack")
            motion.x = 0
            timer.paused
        States.Follow:
            state_machine.travel("attention")
            timer.paused = true
            

func handle_movement():
    # Floor check
    if RayFloor.is_colliding():
        if dir >= 1:
            motion.x = speed
            state_machine.travel("run")
        else:
            motion.x = -speed
            state_machine.travel("run")
        # Reset the timer when the floor is colliding
        timer.wait_time = rand_range(2.0, 4.0)
        timer.start()
    else:
        # If the floor is not colliding, stop movement
        motion.x = 0
        state_machine.travel("idle")

    # Wall check
    if RayWall.is_colliding():
        dir = -dir
        scale.x *= dir
    
    motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2.UP)


func _on_Timer_timeout():
    dir = -dir
    scale.x *= -1
    timer.wait_time = rand_range(1.0, 3.0)


func _on_check_box_body_entered(body):
    if body.is_in_group("player"):
        current_state = States.Follow


func _on_check_box_body_exited(body):
    if body.is_in_group("player"):
        current_state = States.RUN
        timer.paused = false
    

func follow_player():
    if player:
        var direction = (player.global_position - global_position).normalized()
        var velocity = direction * speed

        # Apply gravity
        velocity.y += gravity

        # Move the enemy
        move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
```

Comment: What is your problem? You posted code which already has code to handle the follow part, but you are not calling it, as far as I can see from the bit of code. What exactly is not working?

Comment: i call it in attention animation like a track but i am ask if there a better way to make the enemy follow the player and if there an error or bug in my code

Comment: For more general, opinion-based inquiries about improving your code without a specific issue, consider posting on the Godot Community (https://godot.community/) or Code Review Stack Exchange (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), noting that the latter has fewer Godot users, but you can pose this as a general game development question, rather than one specific to a particular engine.